# How to give a correct margin space between <p> and <h2> tags

Tags: css

I have some body text which is roughly like this:

```
<p>Article nor prepare chicken you him now. Shy merits say advice ten before lovers innate add.</p>
<h2>Do commanded an shameless we disposing do</h2>
<p>Do commanded an shameless we disposing do. Indulgence ten remarkably nor are impression out. Power is lived means oh every in we quiet.</p>
<h2>Alteration unaffected impossible ye</h2>
<p>For saw half than cold. Pretty merits waited six talked pulled you. </p>
```

I want to give some decent spacing between the `h2` and `p` element, so that the reader knows they are reading a new section of the document. `p` is 160% (16px) in size and `h2` is about 220% (22px) size.

The ideal distance between them looks around 15px. But that is a fixed value so instead I did this:

```
p + h2 {margin-top: 1em} /* instead of margin-top:15px */
```

It looks fine, but I'm not sure if its correct by the rules of text layout. Because now the margin-top value equates to 22px due to the size of the `h2` tag.

Am I doing it right, or is there a proper way of doing it? My concern is that if the `h2` font-size increases but the `p` element doesn't, then the margin will be gigantic between them and look stupid.

Comment: Hmm. I would suggest using em for both the p and h2 font size, to keep it consistent. Percent for font size will look funny when the user resizes their browser, especially on a desktop.

Comment: Use rem units for sizing that doesn’t need em units, and that should scale depending on browser font size settings.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you just need to give your elements some padding, and use classes if you want it specific to certain elements.

Here is some JS fiddle with classes assigned to the P elements

```
<p class="textspan">Article nor prepare chicken you him now. Shy merits say advice ten before lovers innate add.</p>

.textspan{
padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhbsdbjp/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.It will push everything away from the

block by 15px from the top and from the bottom.

```
p {margin-top: 15px, margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

[enter link description here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssspacing.html)